# how to start fitting a model?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, modeling

I am doing multiple linear regression and i am using this data:https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Forest+Fires

(assuming I have did the transformation on y)

it turns out the data contain 4 categorical data and 8 continuous data, when i try to fit a model with considering the pair relationship and the 4+8 variables. The **rsquare is low**~0.4.Also i am trying to test whether the interaction terms are significant or not. I look up the results and find that many of **p value are large including the 4+8 variables**. Am i doing the wrong things?Can someone give me some h**ints or keywords** so that i can google it.

Comment: In fact your categorical variables when represented by dummy variables add up to many more than 4 variables in your model (well 33 by my count) so you have 41 variables in total. If you are then adding all the two way interactions (not clear how many you are using) then you may be trying to use too complex a model for your data-set.

Comment: Actually this is one of the problem that i am facing. I tried to ignore some of the categorical variables (e.g. the spatial coordinate) but I can not find any proper reason to ignore it.In general how can i show that not consider some categorical variables is reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the step-wise multiple linear regression. The step wise method selects the best remaining variable according to minimum BIC or P value.